# Flatten nested data-structure in a non-complete RxJS stream

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx

I want to flatten the values I get from the store and emit them as a single array when store emits.

It is quite easy in a synchronous version from my *No-RxJS* example below, but I can't figure out how to do it with RxJS.

I assume I could use RxJS to buffer values from a single `.next` call.

Should I use RxJS operators for that? If yes, then how do I make the nested data structure flat?

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```js
const store$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject([])

store$.next([
  {
    id: 1,
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Foo'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bar'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    items: [
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Fizz'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Buzz'
      }
    ]
  },
]);

// Desired output: [ "Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Buzz" ]

store$
  .filter(({length}) => length > 0)
  .flatMap(group => group)
  .flatMap(({items}) => items)
  .map(({title}) => title)
  .subscribe(console.log) // Emits separate values :-(

// No-RxJs approach

store$
  .filter(({length}) => length > 0)
  .map(groups => groups
        .map(
          ({ items }) => items.map(
            ({ title }) => title
          )
        )
        .reduce((next, acc) => [ ...acc, ...next ], []))
  .subscribe(console.log) // Works as expected.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem is that the stream doesn't complete, so you cannot reduce data. If you are fine with a stream that completes you can simply call `toArray()`. I wonder why you call your second example "No RxJs".

Comment: @zeroflagL sorry for confusion, it relies on native array methods for flattening the array, that's primarily why.

Comment: I see. What about the non-completing stream then?

Comment: @zeroflagL it works if I `switchMap` to the same stream but with `take(1)`, looks like that is the solution, if I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Or `.take(4)` and `.toArray()`?

Comment: @Riscie that wouldn't work in my case, since the number of items is dynamic.

Comment: @zeroflagL would you like to post a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [@zeroflagl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151351/zeroflagl) in comments, [toArray](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray) method worked like a charm.

Since it works only on completed observables, I've had to `swithchMap` to an Observable, which uses `take(1)` to get a completed observable with current store value.

```
store$
    .filter(({ length }) => length > 0)
    .switchMap(() => store$.take(1)
        .flatMap(group => group)
        .flatMap(({ items }) => items)
        .map(({ title }) => title)
        .toArray()
    )
    .subscribe(console.log) // Emits flat array
```